# How to dynamically populate table based on data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

**This is my HTML code**

```
<table data-role="table" id="movie-table" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterTable-input" class="ui-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-priority="1">Rank</th>
            <th data-priority="persist">Player Name</th>
            <th data-priority="2">Record</th>
            <th data-priority="3"><abbr title="Rotten Tomato Rating">Points</abbr></th>
            <th data-priority="4">Highlight</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
        <div id="table"></table>


        </tbody>
    </table>
**This is my Javascript/Jquery**
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
$.get('./php/rank.php', function(data)
 {
 $('#table').html(data);



}).error(function() {

 $('#table').append('An error has occured');


} ).success (function(){

 $('#table').append(''); 

})




});
**This is my php**
echo "<tr>";    
         echo "<th>". $row1['points']."<td/>";
    echo "<td>". $row1['points']."<td/>";
    echo "<td>". $row1['points']."<td/>";
       echo "<td>". $row1['points']."<td/>";
        echo "<td>". $row1['points']."<td/>";
echo "</tr>";
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to populate the table based on registered users. I 
tried to echo the complete table - no success(I'm using JQuery Mobile) So I thought                        maybe I can Just Echo the th and td tags that will vary. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, maybe I'm just going about this the wrong way. Thanks

Comment: Where does `$row1` come from? PHP is processed on the server and then sent to the client where the page is rendered and the JavaScript processed.

Comment: here is the issue .success (function(){

 $('#table').append('');  should be .success (function(data){

 $('#table').append(data);

Comment: $row1 comes from mysql fetch array. I guess I wasnt clear, but I'm not getting any syntax errors. My issue is JQuery mobile format. I'm using phonegap and in order to use php with phonegap I need to use Ajax or something similar. I just want to get the data from my mysql database in JQuery mobile table format dynamically. The table will rank users, I dont know how many users I will have so I need it to update as need. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. In php you have to echo the complete table.

```
echo "<table data-role='table' id='movie-table' data-filter='true' data-input='#filterTable-input' class='ui-responsive'>";
  echo  "<thead>";

echo "<tr>";
           echo "<th data-priority='1'>Rank</th>";
            echo "<th data-priority='persist'>Player Name</th>";
           echo "<th data-priority='2'>Record</th>";
           echo "<th data-priority='3'><abbr title='Rotten Tomato Rating'>Points</abbr></th>";
            echo "<th data-priority='4'>Highlight</th>";
    echo    "</tr>";
      echo  "</thead>";

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){ 



       echo "<tbody>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>1</th>";
                echo "<td>Kentwan</td>";
                echo "<td>10-0</td>";
                echo "<td>1000</td>";
               echo "<td>test</td>";
            echo "</tr>";


        echo "</tbody>";

}


echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing your tags properly. Moreover, there is no need for a `div` insde `tbody` (I don't know if it's even allowed). Try with this corrected code:

```
<table data-role="table" id="movie-table" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterTable-input" class="ui-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-priority="1">Rank</th>
            <th data-priority="persist">Player Name</th>
            <th data-priority="2">Record</th>
            <th data-priority="3"><abbr title="Rotten Tomato Rating">Points</abbr></th>
            <th data-priority="4">Highlight</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
**This is my Javascript/Jquery**
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
$.get('./php/rank.php', function(data)
 {
 $('#movie-table tbody').html(data);



}).error(function() {

 $('#movie-table tbody').append('An error has occured');


} ).success (function(){

 $('#movie-table tbody').append(''); 

})




});
**This is my php**
echo "<tr>";    
         echo "<th>". $row1['points']."</th>";
    echo "<td>". $row1['points']."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row1['points']."</td>";
       echo "<td>". $row1['points']."</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row1['points']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

**Edit:** and of course you don't want to show the field "points" in all of the five columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<table data-role="table" id="movie-table" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterTable-input" class="ui-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-priority="1">Rank</th>
            <th data-priority="persist">Player Name</th>
            <th data-priority="2">Record</th>
            <th data-priority="3"><abbr title="Rotten Tomato Rating">Points</abbr></th>
            <th data-priority="4">Highlight</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id='tab_body'>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

** your Javascript/Jquery**

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
$.get('./php/rank.php', function(data)
 {
 $('#tab_body').html(data);

})
}
```